# EC2 Ubuntu Server NICE DCV "Error: unable to open display :0"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vnc, omniverse

I'm trying to set up a GUI on my EC2 instance following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/adminguide/setting-up-installing-linux-prereq.html).

When I try to run the command

`sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=$(ps aux | grep "X.*\-auth" | grep -v grep | sed -n 's/.*-auth \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p') glxinfo | grep -i "opengl.*version"`

I get an error saying that

`Error: unable to open display :0`

I'm running a G4 instance with Nvidia's Omniverse AMI if that helps. I'm pretty new to this so if there's a better way to set up a GUI that also would work.

Comment: You're setting an environment variable DISPLAY to ":0" and then something is trying to use it. Did you copy this code from somewhere? Try with DISPLAY=0?

Comment: Yeah I copied the code from the link I posted. I've tried multiple things, the only one that gives me something different is 'DISPLAY=:10.0' and now I get: 'X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.'